# Perl query about data structure

Tags: perl, data-structures, hash, perl-data-structures

I currently use the following hash which works fine

```
%hash = ( 
    'env1' => 'server1:port1, server11:port11',
    'env2' => 'server2:port2, server22:port22'
) ;
```

However, what I really want to do is create the following data structure, which will make it easier for me to extract the information. The following obviously does not work.

```
(
  env1 => "server=server1, port=port1", "server=server11, port=port11",
  env2 => "server=server2, port=port2", "server=server22, port=port22"
) ;
```

Wondering if anyone has any suggestions on creating a data structure that would match my requirements.

Comment: How do you generate the first hash to begin with?

Comment: How do you intend to use the values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write this:

```
%hash = (
  env1 => ["server=server1, port=port1", "server=server11, port=port11"],
  env2 => ["server=server2, port=port2", "server=server22, port=port22"]
) ;
```

And then access elements like this:

```
$hash{'env1'}->[0] == "server=server1, port=port1"
$hash{'env2'}->[1] == "server=server22, port=port22"
```

This is a hash where the values are references to anonymous arrays.

But when I look at you data I think maybe there is a better way to store it:

```
%hash = (
  env1 => [{'server' => 'server1', 'port' => 'port1'}, {'server' => 'server11', 'port' => 'port11'}],
  env2 => [{'server' => 'server2', 'port' => 'port2'}, {'server' => 'server22', 'port' => 'port22'}]
) ;
```

And then access elements like this:

```
$hash{'env1'}->[0]->{'server'} == "server1"
$hash{'env2'}->[1]->{'port'} == "port22"
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. I am still working on building a loop which will go over the above hash (the latter portion of your post), but the details that you provided are exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly what you're looking for given the question.  I suspect a hash of hashes will suffice.  You'd set it up like this:

```
%hash = ( 'env1' => { 'server' => 'server1', 'port' => 'port1' }, 
          'env2' => { 'server' => 'server2', 'port' => 'port2' } );
```

To get the values, you'd do something like this:

```
print $hash{'env2'}->{'server'};
```

You can add additional values like this:

```
$hash{'env3'} = {'server' => 'server3', 'port' => 'port3'};
```